# Terminal Server on DC: When user closes his environment program there is no logoff, also no Remote Control

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller, terminal-server

I installed Terminal Services on Windows 2003 DC, configured everything and successfully connected as a Terminal user from another ws.

I configured in AD Users and Computer under the 'Environment' tab, 'Start the following program at logon' the calc.exe to run. The instructor clearly said that if you close it, the session disconnects. I loged on witht he user, closed the calculator and was left with a grey desktop. The session remains open.

Another issue is that although I enabled remote control under 'Remote Control' tab, when I right-click a user session under Terminal Services Manager, 'Remote Control' is greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

About the Remote Control:
The Administrator also has to be connected to Terminal Services to Remote Control a user.